# How to use a previous numerical solution to solve a differential equation numerically?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

When I solve this differential equation with NDSolve, I get a numerical solution for H[x]:

**Code for the differential equation:**

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{(H'[x])^2 - ((1 + 6 H[x]^2)^2 H[x]^2)/(
 6 (1 + 18 H[x]^2)) + ((1 + 6 H[x]^2)^2 E^-x)/(
 18 (1 + 18 H[x]^2)) == 0, H[0] == 1}, H, {x, 0, 20}]
```

I want to use the numerical solution (The solution that I get for the equation that is above) for solving numerically this equation ( I want to get x[t])

**Code for the equation that I want to solve**

```
x'[t] == -2 H'[x]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: x'[t] == -2 H'[x] /. sol1

Comment: `sol1=NDSolve[{system},H[x],{x,0,1.7}]` because your system appears to blow up beyond 1.7 then `Plot[H[x]/.sol1,{x,0,1.7}]` then `x1=Integrate[-2*H[x]/.sol1[[1]],x]` and `x2=Integrate[-2*H[x]/.sol1[[2]],x]` because there appear to be two solutions then `Plot[{x1,x2},{x,0,1.7}]` and `x1/.x->1.0` to find the value of x1 when t==1.0

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol1 = NDSolve[{(H'[
         x])^2 - ((1 + 6 H[x]^2)^2 H[x]^2)/(6 (1 + 
           18 H[x]^2)) + ((1 + 6 H[x]^2)^2 E^-x)/(18 (1 + 
           18 H[x]^2)) == 0, H[0] == 1}, H[x], {x, 0, 20}] // Flatten
```

We get 2 branches of the solution.  The first branch is well-behaved and the second blows up at about `x = 1.73`  I will use the first well-behaved branch.

```
H1[x_] = H[x] /. sol1[[1]];

Plot[H1[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

For the second part

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == -2 H1'[x[t]], x[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 20}] // Flatten;

x[t_] = x[t] /. %

Plot[x[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Check the solution

```
Plot[{x'[t], (-2 H1'[x[t]])}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

They pretty much overlay.  Or more accurately:

```
Plot[{x'[t] - (-2 H1'[x[t]])}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]